# What is the best way to pull from a private github remote in python?

Tags: python, git, github

I want to write a program which allows me to pull my git remote without having to type my username and password all the time.

When I use `git pull` in terminal i get this output:

*Username for 'https://github.com':*

*Password for 'https://github.com':*

After googling on the issue, I found this

```
import os
os.system("git pull")
```

Now I need to know if it's possible to set my username and password in the python program so I don't need to put it in myself.

Comment: You could save your git credentials…

Comment: Python is not the best way to do this. You should try [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a name and especially password directly inside the code of any program is dirty and you definitely want to avoid this for several reasons.

In this case, I suggest using SSH keys to authorize without the need of password. Refer to [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/) for info on how to achieve this. Once your SSH keys are setup, make sure to use `ssh://` repository links instead of `https://`.

Comment: To add to this: make sure you clone you're repo with SSH instead of HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

If you're really stuck on using `https` instead of the `ssh` protocol as your remote URL for whatever reason (GitHub actually [recommends](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) it), might I suggest making use of git's [credential caching](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) to make life easier. Just use:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache [options]'
```

For example, issuing the command

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

will add

```
[credential]
helper = cache --timeout=3600
```

to your `gitconfig` file, forcing you to only enter your password once every hour for the given remote.